# Publish Python Game

Tags: python, publishing

I wrote a Python game in for a group project using Pygame.  Now we wanted to package it into an executable but I can't seem to do it.  When I was working with C# through Microsoft Visual Studio it had a really simple publish feature.  Is there an editor that can do that for Python with external libraries?

Comment: Also is 4 years old @Philipp

Comment: it got mentioned as a duplicate from another question, so I want to redirect them all to one question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had luck compiling to executable using [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/).
Another possibility, as Luiz mentions, is [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/).

Both of these tools have options to bundle all of the python libraries into the executable if you want, making it easy to distribute.  Either of these might have issues with whatever libraries you might be using, so it might be easiest to check the forum of the libraries you're using to see if they have a recommendation.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I'm really new in Python's World.
But maybe [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) can help you.

Comment: when I was googling this I heard about some problems that I really didn't understand enough to re-explain them, but if there's another option I would prefer it!  Thanks though, I'll select your answer if no other choices come out

Answer (score 0):

The technical part of publishing is described correctly in Luiz's answer, but publishing also involves licensing your game, usually. For that, I suggest you use the Mit license, if you plan to make it unprofitable and aopen-source.

Comment: i should have specified, i plan to just distribute it to friends and don't mind if code is taken from it without acknowledgement