# If I create a pygame, can I later convert it to a .exe for everyone to use?

Tags: pygame

I was told if I create a pygame, other people would need python/pygame to actually run it. Is that true? Or is there a way I can later convert it to a .exe?

Comment: Also: [Publish Python Game](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/33111/publish-python-game).